# Angular - subscribe to http service callback

Tags: javascript, angular, callback

I'm struggling to understand this..

In my `requests.service` I have this function that calls my backend:

```
loginUser(username, pw): Observable <any>{
    const body = {
      username: username,
      password: pw
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('test:test'));
    headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

   return this.http.post('https://website.com/1/user/login', body, {headers: headers})
   .subscribe((data)=>{ //use methods in our service
     console.log(data)
     this.userData = data;
   }, (err)=> console.log(err));
  }
```

This works, the `data` is returned.

Now, in `login.page.ts` I want to call `loginUser` but I also want a callback on it so I know when it has successfully been run, so I do:

```
this.req.loginUser(info.email, info.password).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

but I get the error:

> this.req.loginUser(...).then is not a function

If I just `console.log` it with no callback it works fine, but I need to know when the call has been successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: You return a subscription not a promise, then() will never work in this example. Just do the call without the then(): `this.req.loginUser(info.email, info.password);` you will not need it.

Comment: Return the observable from the service... please look at the tutorial, it will help you: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull but how do I know when the call has executed? I need to run code after..

Comment: just return the observable without the subscription in the service. you can `.pipe(tap((data) => { ... }))` if you need logic in the service and make the subscription in your component.

Comment: `loginUser` return a subscription object not observable please consider look to my answer  where I explain observable and promise implementation  @JaneDoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an observable coming back not a promise. So `.then` is not applicable.

```
this.req.loginUser(info.email, info.password).pipe().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data) // whenever data returns do something with it
})
```

We use [pipe()](https://blog.angularindepth.com/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe-94d51fec71c2) to be able to do more things with subscriptions such as:

```
.pipe(
   take(1) // will allow the subscription to return 1 time then unsubscribe 
   takeUntil() // subscribe until a condition is met
   map() // map your observable
   etc.
)
```

Comment: correct but look he already subscribe inside the method check my answer 

Answer (score 2):

Since `loginUser` returns an `Observable`, you need to `subscribe` to it.

```
this.req.loginUser(info.email, info.password).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: loginUser dosn't return an observable because he subscribe inside the method is return subscription object  you answer correct in case he return the post method without the subscribe

Answer (score 2):

you need to update the `loginUser` like this in case you want to use the observable and you don't need to subscribe inside the loginUser

```
loginUser(username, pw): Observable <any>{
    const body = {
      username: username,
      password: pw
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('test:test'));
    headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const url = 'https://website.com/1/user/login';
   return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers}); // 

  }
```

invoke the method like this

```
this.req.loginUser(info.email, info.password).subscribe((data)=>{ 
         console.log(data);
         this.userData = data;
}, (err)=>{
         console.log(err)
});
```

in case you want to use the then method and you want to invoke the method imidaily
use toPromise method to convert the observable to promise

```
loginUser(username, pw): Promise <any>{
    const body = {
      username: username,
      password: pw
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('test:test'));
    headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const url = 'https://website.com/1/user/login';
   return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers}).toPromise(); // 

  }
```

now you can use the then method

```
this.req.loginUser(info.email, info.password).then((data)=>{ 
         console.log(data);
         this.userData = data;
 }).
 catch( err => console.log(err));
```

> The key difference between two ways if it observable this  `this.req.login
>   User(info.email, info.password)` will not run until you subscribe but
>   in case of promise this  `this.req.login User(info.email, info.password)`
>   will run the method even without using then the request will send to
>   the server